# Ionic tabs are displaying in bottom by default

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to display ionic tabs on top of the the page but for no reason its not happening. I tried explicitly putting `$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('top');` in `.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider)` but nothing changes.

Here is my code

```
<div class = "tabs-striped tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
<div class = "tabs">
<a class = "tab-item">
<i class = "icon ion-home"></i>
</a>        
<a class = "tab-item active">
<i class = "icon ion-star"></i>
</a>
<a class = "tab-item">
<i class = "icon ion-planet"></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-tabs class="has-tabs-top">
  //here put your all tabs
</ion-tabs>
```

second method you can override the ionic css default properties:

```
@media not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, (min-resolution: 144dpi), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)
.tabs {
padding-top: 2px;
border-top: none !important;
border-bottom: none;
background-position: top;
background-size: 100% 1px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
**position: fixed;
top: 0px;**
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I put your code in second method in internal style sheet that worked for me :)